# Not printing the position of recyclerView in logcat

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to print the position of RecyclerView in logcat when I click on the list of recyclerView, but it's not printing anything. Actually in this app, if I click on a position of the recyclerview, that should take me to new activity and grab all the details of that position on which I clicked.

Here is my ImageAdapter.java class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<UserDetails> mUploads;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;


public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}


public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<UserDetails> uploads) {
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_display, viewGroup, false);

    return new ImageViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder, int i) {

    UserDetails currentItem = mUploads.get(i);

    UserDetails userDetails = mUploads.get(i);
    imageViewHolder.requestId.setText("Request Id : " + userDetails.getMobileNumber());
    imageViewHolder.customerName.setText(userDetails.getName());
    imageViewHolder.customerMobile.setText("Mobile : " + userDetails.getMobileNumber());
    imageViewHolder.customerAddress.setText(userDetails.getAddress());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView requestId, customerName, customerAddress, customerMobile, serviceType, date;

    public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        requestId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.requestId);
        customerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customerName);
        customerAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customerAddress);
        customerMobile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customerMobile);
        serviceType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.serviceType);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        mListener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

}
and here is the recyclerView class

```
public class requestList extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

List<UserDetails> downloadDataArray;

ImageAdapter adapter;

ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_request_list);

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.roServiceToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Requests");
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(requestList.this, customerRequests.class));
        }
    });

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    downloadDataArray = new ArrayList<>();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Service Request/RO Service");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            downloadDataArray.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserDetails userDetails = postSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);
                downloadDataArray.add(userDetails);
            }

            adapter = new ImageAdapter(requestList.this, downloadDataArray);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Requests" + "(" +adapter.getItemCount()+ ")");
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Log.i("Position", String.valueOf(position));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                 //print log message
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not assigning the value of `mListener`. Add this line after initialize adapter object.

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)
```

Comment: Add some log in `onClick()` function and confirm it is working.